# Плюсы и минусы двух связок для php7 - nginx/apache/mod_php vs nginx/php-fpm

Tags: php, apache, php-fpm

Профи, подскажите, какие преимущества и недостатки у бекенд-серверов для php7, apache/mod_php vs php_fpm.

Nginx в обоих случаях будет в качестве фронтенд-сервера.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы понять, ответьте себе на вопрос: зачем на проекте Apache2? Какие дополнительные возможности он вносит?

### fpm

- быстрее вся цепочка "запрос" - "ответ", нет промежуточного звена
- не нужно держать бесполезный Apache2 => экономия ресурсов памяти и процессора
- минус: придется создавать правила nginx для нормальной работы CMS, так как большинство CMS идет с конфигом `.htaccess` под Апач. Но это не сложно

### mod_php

- единственное значимое преимущество - возможность переопределять конфиги через `.htaccess`, что удобно для шаред-хостингов
- самый главный минус - каждый запрос запускает форк апача, [хотя тут пишут, что уже нет](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16747301/does-apache-really-fork-in-mod-php-python-way-for-request-handling)
- если нет Nginx, апачу придется кормить с ложечки все медленные соединения и постоянно потреблять под это память. Если есть Nginx, то он отдает весь ответ ему, и этим уже занимается более экономичный по памяти Nginx

Конечно, Апач имеет кучу возможностей, изысканных ([реврайтинг в зависимости от времени](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/advanced.html#time-dependent), [On-the-fly Content-Regeneration](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/advanced.html#on-the-fly-content)), уникальных, но спросите себя - они вам нужны?

Резюме: fpm, если умеете, и изыски не нужны